# Modificar URL para descargar informe

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssrs

Estoy utilizando `SQL Server Reporting Services (SSRS)` y quiero descargar un informe sin la necesidad de acceder al servidor para ver el reporte, sino automáticamente descargar el reporte en la computadora del usuario.

Quiero ver la posibilidad de modificar el `URL` que se genera al momento descargar el informe para así no tener la necesidad de acceder al servidor de informes.

Tengo el siguiente enlace como ejemplo en el que `ExecutionID` y `ControlID` son lo único que cambia entre cada informe, que es lo que quiero modificar para generar el informe:

> http//desktop/ReportServer_REPORTING/Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd?**ExecutionID=odqvp545iftj02itotwxovn2**&Culture=3082&CultureOverrides=False&UICulture=10&UICultureOverrides=False&ReportStack=1&**ControlID=9426f50bab5445b19b8c1b88e728c8f2**&OpType=Export&FileName=DEMO&ContentDisposition=OnlyHtmlInline&Format=PDF

Answer (score 0):

Yo tengo algo parecido, no se si es lo que necesitas tu. Yo lo que tengo es un proceso que el día 1 del mes ejecuta una llamada para descargar el informe y guardarlo localmente. En mi caso, lo estoy haciendo de la siguiente manera. Estoy invocando la siguiente url (adaptado a tus necesidades):

> http://{{SERVIDOR}}/ReportServer?{{RUTA_DEL_INFORME&rc:Parameters=False&rs:Command=Render&rs:Format=EXCEL&ExecutionID=odqvp545iftj02itotwxovn2&ControlID=9426f50bab5445b19b8c1b88e728c8f2

Puedes cambiar el render para generarlo en el formato que te haga falta.

Espero que te sirva.